# Dynamically including javascript files only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function I'm writing which is being used to include an external JS file, but only once. The reason I need such a function is because it is being called when some content is loaded via AJAX and I need to run page-specific code to that content (no, just using `.live` won't cover it).

Here's my attempt, shortened for brevity:

```
$.include_once = function(filename) {
    if ($("script[src='" + filename + "']").length === 0) {
        var $node = $("<script></script>")
            .attr({
                src : filename,
                type : "text/javascript"
            })
        ;
        $(document.body).append($node);
    }
};
```

This works fine: the function is called, it loads the external file, and that file is being run when loaded. Perfect.

The problem is that it will always re-load that external file: the query I'm using to check for the presence of the script always finds nothing!

When debugging this, I added some lines:

```
alert($("script").length);     // alerts: 4
$(document.body).append($node);
alert($("script").length);     // alerts: 4
```

Looking in the dynamic source (the HTML tab of Firebug), I can't find the script tag at all.

I know that I could maintain an array of files that I've previously included, but I was hoping to go with a method such as this, which (if it worked), seems a bit more robust, since not all the JS files are being included in this way.

**Can anyone explain the behaviour seen in this second snippet?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is a bit of a dumb-dumb in this case; it doesn't do at all what you'd expect. When you `append($node)` jQuery does this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: $node.src,
  async: false,
  dataType: "script"
})
```

Woops! For local files (eg on the same domain) jQuery performs a standard `XMLHttpRequest` for the .js file body, and proceeds to "eval" it by a whole convoluted process of creating a `<script>` tag (again!) and settings it's *contents* to your .js file body. This is to simulate `eval` but in the global context.

For cross-domain files, since it cannot perform the standard `XMLHttpRequest` due to the same-domain policy, jQuery once again creates a `<script>` element and inserts it into `<head>`.

In both the local and cross-domain cases above jQuery *finally* gets around to doing this:

```
head.removeChild(script);
```

And *booms* your `.length` check! Bummer.

So on to your problem, don't bother jQuery with this. Just do

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
  .appendChild(
    document.createElement('script')
  )
  .src = filename;
```

Which will do what you'd expect, particularly wrt querying for it later.

Comment: Excellent response. I figured jQuery was being a bit too clever for itself or something.

Comment: @nickf: I feel that way about most of jQuery's innards (being too clever that is ;) There's lots of necessary evils in there I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to solve a problem that has already been solved several times over. Try [LazyLoad](http://wonko.com/post/painless_javascript_lazy_loading_with_lazyload) for example. There are also similar plugins for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the source attribute of the script-tag, set the "text" attribute of the script tag. This works in all *modern* browsers (the application where I use that in practice does not support IE6, so I do not know about this creep...).

In practice it would look like this (you HAVE TO add code to omit double inclusion on yourself - e.g. a simple array of all alread loaded scripts, though thats very application specific, and why should you anyway load code twice? try to omit double-loading code...!):

```
var script_source_code_string = <some dynamically loaded script source code>;
var $n = $("<script></script>");
$n.get(0).text = script_source_code_string;
$(document.body).append($n);
```

Or even simpler (without jquery, my code at this stage does not know jquery, it may also be loaded dynamically):

```
var script_source_code_string = <some dynamically loaded script source code>;
var s = document.createElement('script');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
s.text = script_source_code_string;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the function I use to load external script and style files dynamically into my page, considering not to load an script twice and detecting both '.css' and '.js' extentions.

```
function lazyLoad(src) {
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (head.innerHTML.search(src) == -1) {
        if (src.search('.js') > -1) {
            var node = document.createElement('script');
            node.src = src;
            node.async = false;
            node.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');
        
            head.appendChild(node);
        } else if (src.search('.css') > -1) {
            var node = document.createElement('link');
            node.href = src;
            node.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
            node.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');

            head.appendChild(node);
        }
    }
}
```